# Prefix "a-" in abash, abeyance and agape

Tags: etymology

From Wiktionary,

"[abash](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abash)" means "To make ashamed; to embarrass; to destroy the self-possession of, as by exciting suddenly a consciousness of guilt, mistake, or inferiority; to disconcert; to discomfit."

"[abeyance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abeyance)" means "Suspension; temporary suppression; dormant condition"

"[agape](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agape)" means "Being in a state of astonishment, wonder, expectation, or eager attention; as with mouth hanging open. "

In the given links, I found that

- in "abash" and "abeyance", "bash" and "bey" both mean gape, i.e. open mouth wide. In the three words, are the meanings and reasons of "gape" the same?
- "a-" in "abash" means "ex- (“out of”)", and in "abeyance" means "to". I am not sure about "a-" in "agape" ( meaning "in")?

Why do the three words mean so differently, given that they basically have the same prefix "a-" and root "gape"? I haven't understood yet, but the above is what I have found.

Comment: That Wiktionary definition of "agape" seems wrong, or at least confined to some specific philosophy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why do the three words mean so differently, given that they basically have the same prefix "a-" and root "gape"? I haven't understood yet, but the above is what I have found.

Semantic shifts can be one of the trickiest and most difficult-to-nail-down aspects of language evolution. There is no real way of answering the question ‘why’ about it—but it is often possible (with a bit of tinkering) to answer the question ‘how’.

#### Agape

‘Agape’ is a formation made within English itself. The prefix *a-* is quite productive in English, used to denote adjectives and adverbs that describe some state, manner, or activity (‘asleep’, ‘aloud’, “There she was just *a-walkin’* down the street”). Its origin is as an unstressed reduction of the preposition ‘on’.

‘Gape’ is a common enough word in English, and it needs no further explanation, really. ‘Agape’ as a whole is also quite self-explanatory and basically means what it looks like. Its semantic shift is more or less nonexistent.

#### Abash

As you have correctly identified, this comes from the (Latin) prefix *ex-* plus a verbal stem meaning to gape or to yawn. *Ex-* in this particular word does not really have its most common meaning of ‘out of’, but is rather an intensifier, just like *per-* (literally ‘through’) and its Germanic counterpart, (English) *for-*, so often is.

In other words, abashing someone really means something like ‘pergaping’ or ‘forgaping’ them—to make them stand there with their mouth utterly open, dumbstruck. It is not hard to see how the modern meaning of the verb has developed from this.

#### Abeyance

This word has the same gaping root (**bay-/be(y)-*) as the previous one; but in this word, the deceptively similar *a-* prefix is quite a different one: it is the variant of the (Latin) prefix *ad-* regularly found before b, so it’s really ‘adbeyance’ in the underlying form (similarly, ‘abet’ and ‘abate’ are underlyingly ‘adbet’ and ‘adbate’), or ‘gaping towards [something]’.

This is the word that has the most winding history of the three. The original meaning of ‘gaping towards’ something is to be eagerly desirous of it, a meaning that makes a good deal of sense (similar to how you can be ‘gasping for’ something). It was apparently especially used of someone who desired or expected to receive property (for whatever reason). From there was formed the noun (Old French) *abeance* (Anglo-French *abeiance*), which meant something like ‘the condition of someone who’s expecting/hoping to receive property’, in which sense it was used in French law.

When the word joined English, a somewhat odd development took place: it started to be used instead of the property that the person was expecting/hoping to receive. In a legal sense, that property would obviously usually be temporarily without an owner, which is what gave the abeyant (in the former sense) person hope/expectations of claiming it. So the English went from saying that the *person* was in abeyance of the property, to saying that the *property* was in abeyance because someone was expecting to receive it.

Thence came the current legal sense: “the position of being without, or waiting for, an owner or claimant”.

Of course, when property has no owner, it in a state of limbo, as it were, and this sense of being somehow ‘put on hold’ was then generalised to other, non-property-like, things, to give the current sense of being simply ‘suspended’ or ‘on hold’ in general.

Comment: Thanks! Is it right in abash,a- is actually ab-? How can I tell whether a- infront of b is ab- or ad-?

Comment: No, it is _ex-_, not _ab-_. There are attestations from Old French with the s still present. I can't think of any examples of _ab-_ + _b-_, but if initial p is anything to go by! it would probably be _absb-_.

Comment: Doesn't ab- also mean away from and out of, just like ex-?

Comment: Yes, they have very similar meanings. _Ab-_ is mostly ‘away from’ and _ex-_ is mostly ‘out of’, but just like ‘of’ and ‘from’ in English, their meanings overlap.

Comment: But none of these words contains the prefix ab-.

Comment: "gape" is not a root word.

Comment: @user49727, what do you mean by ‘root word’?

Comment: as opposed to a stem word

Comment: I know of word stems and word roots, but not of root words and stem words. ‘Gape’ is both a root and a stem (both as a noun and as a verb) in English; I still don’t see what you’re referring to here.

Comment: Nope. Gape has further PIE roots. So it is not a root. Or root word if you prefer.

Comment: Well, obviously. That applies to more or less every word in the English language. That doesn’t change the fact that it is both a root and a stem _in English_. ‘Root’ does not necessarily equal ‘root in a previous, reconstructed stage of the language’. How is this relevant, anyway? I never even mentioned the word ‘root’ in my answer.

Comment: Again, that's not true. There are many English Language words that are both roots and stems. Run for example. But agape is several orders away from being a root.

Comment: ‘Run’ also has PIE roots and is not the ‘original’ root word. And you said ‘gape’ before, not ‘agape’. And this is still _completely irrelevant_.

Comment: Gape too has another stem - gap - which in turn has a PIE root.

Comment: So? These are separate words, separate roots, and separate stems in English. That they are etymologically related is irrelevant to their synchronic status as words, roots, or stems. And the whole discussion of stems and roots is, once again, _completely irrelevant to this answer, which mentions neither_.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10957/discussion-between-janus-bahs-jacquet-and-user49727)

Comment: sure - the whole point is that the grammatical form of the stem makes a crucial difference in the way words are conjugated with prefixes and prepositions, altering their meanings significantly.

Answer (score 1):

The prepostion *a-* in **agape** serves the function of reinforcing the present participle form of the verb stem *gape* (just as in *ablaze*) - giving the sense of adding *on* (*on gape*) - thus turning the verb stem into an adjective (or an adverb).

The preposition *a-* in **abeyance** serves a similar reinforcing function and is cognate with *ad-* (with the first consonant being assimilated during the conjugation). The suffix -*ance* turns the stem into a noun form.

The prefix *a-* in **abash**, on the other hand, is a mutation of *es-* from *ex-*. *Ex-*
here still means *out of* but is used here in the interjectory sense of *completely, utterly* or *thoroughly* expressing astonishment (just like the intensive prefix in *aghast*). Since the prefix serves merely an exclamatory function the stem retains its verb form.

Comment: There is no present participle involved in ‘agape’, and the ‘gape’ part is much more likely to be a noun than a verb (preposition + verb is not a common structure, and the _a-_ prefix is regularly used with nouns and adjectives only). The _a-_ in ‘abeyance’ really does not have a reinforcing sense, but a literal sense (originally).

Comment: a- is used here as a present participle. It is in fact given as an illustrating example of such a construction: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/a-

Comment: No, it is not. As that page says, _a-_ is also used “in archaic and dialectal use **before** a present participle in _-ing_”. ‘Gape’ is not a present participle in _-ing_, and that is not the construction found in this word. A present participle is a specific thing, a verbal form; _a-_ is a completely separate issue. Many prefixes can be added to present participles—that does not mean the prefix somehow _is_ the present participle.

Comment: "and added to a verb stem with the force of a present participle ( ablaze; agape; aglow; astride;  and originally, awry  )" ... quoted from the relevant section.

Comment: The **force** of a present participle. That is not the same as “reinforcing the present participle **form** of the verb stem”. Moreover, that’s a quite suspicious-looking phrasing. All the ‘verbs’ that they quote are also nouns, and the OED has them all as being derived from the nouns, not the verbs. The OED does mention that _later_ formations reinterpreted some of these verbal nouns as being verb stems and the prefix started to be added to pure verbs (aflaunt, abask, ablow, achatter), but these are all much later (17th c. on), and ‘agape’ is not one of them.

Comment: I said "serves the function of reinforcing ... ". Moreover Etymonline and Chambers both concur that a- is modifying the verb form. Etymonline also confirms that the verb form was used earlier (as early as the 13c) and the noun form only came about in the 16c.

Comment: Yes, you said it serves the function of reinforcing the present participle _form_ of the verb stem. There is no present participle _form_ for _a-_ to reinforce here. You could say that prefixing to the verb stem _a-_ makes the resulting word much like a present participle; but that is a different thing. Etymonline does not say anything about the noun ‘gape’; but whether the verb or the noun is earlier is irrelevant, since ‘agape’ did not come about until the 17c when both verb and noun were present in the language.

Comment: But it does ... the main entry clearly states that it is a verb - and the link to 'gape' makes the history of this word crystal clear!

Comment: And there is no noun form for agape. The noun agape is a different word with a totally different lineage.

Answer (score 0):

**abash** :

comes from Old French esbahir (es = very much ; bahir = astonish), now written "ébahir", with exactly the same meaning (but without a notion of possible fault as in English)

**abeyance** :

comes from Old French abeiance ( = expectation ; a is not a real prefix, and certainly not Greek as in many other words), now obsolete (but French keeps "bouche bée", meaning that you are so surprised that you leave your mouth open), and "bayer" (= to yawn)

**agape** :

Scandinavian origin (gapa) ; like in many other words (afoot, astray, awash, ...) the "a" is used to form an adjective or an adverb from the substantive. Again, the origin is not the privative Greek "a".

Comment: The _a-_ in Old French _abeiance_ absolutely is a prefix: it is the regular form of (Latin) _ad-_ found before b (cf. ‘abet’). In ‘agape’, _a-_ is a reduction of ‘on’. This answer does not really attempt to answer the actual question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Some "a" words come from Greek, in which case, "a" means "not":  "atom" comes from "a-tomos" = "can't cut".

Comment: Yes, it is usual ; but not in these examples.